# Print MySQL table in php (simple)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having problems printing my MySQL database table into my PHP code. I want the MySQL table to be printed in my website as an actual table, not just the database values. Everything I do doesn't seem to work and I have looked at similar questions to this but still can't get it to work.

Comment: I hope you have enabled remote access to your database... :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that is, please explain how to do so.

Comment: @humzahmalik: What do you mean by "print a table"?  There's no code here which even tries to output anything from the database.  All this code does is try to insert a record to the database.  Where's the code that "prints" anything?

Comment: Where you are trying to print table from database?? The query is about inserting !!

Comment: I haven't put the code in. I wanted someone on here to help me.

Comment: You should take some time and get on php.net learning a little bit of php, what do you wannt to do is imposible without some knowledge. And by the way you have posted you database host, username and password on the internet... this will not end well :)

Comment: Don't worry, it's a temporary password for a test database :)

Comment: @humzahmalik even that don't show it like its an _banana_ !

Comment: @humzahmalik: `"I haven't put the code in. I wanted someone on here to help me."` - We don't really offer tutoring services here.  You might try some introductory tutorials on PHP and MySQL.  Just about any tutorial is going to cover the subject of selecting data from a database and displaying it on a page.

Comment: @humzahmalik did you get what want..??

Comment: whose answer worked for you???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you html form place a submit button with name fetch like this

```
  <form method="post" action="yourphpfilename.php">
 <input type="submit" name ="fetch" value="FETCH DATA" />
 </form>
```

and in your php code insert this code and configure this.

```
  if(isset($_POST['fetch']))
  {
    // Connect to database server
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysqli_error ());

   // Select database
   mysqli_select_db($con,"databasename") or die(mysqli_error());

 // SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename ;

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);


  print "
  <table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border-  collapse: collapse\" bordercolor=\"#808080\" width=\"100&#37;\"    id=\"AutoNumber2\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">
   <tr>
   <td width=100>ID:</td> 
  <td width=100>First Name</td> 
  <td width=100>Last Name</td> 
  <td width=100>Email</td> 
  <td width=100>User Name</td>
  <td width=100>Password</td> 
  <td width=100>Date Of Birth</td> 
  <td width=100>Gender</td> 
  </tr>"; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
 { 
print "<tr>"; 
print "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['dob'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>"; 
print "</tr>"; 
} 
print "</table>"; 

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/2302862).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
    // printing table headers
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    // printing table rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";


        foreach($row as $cell)
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If the OP is using `mysqli_` why do you answer with `mysql_` ? Should I suggest you use prepared statements ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen you used mysqli functions

Comment: if you change the functions to mysqli then this is the best answer by far!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a SELECT statement so you can retrieve the data from the database and save it in a variable. Once you have the data you can print the table using a for-loop.